# How to get nanoseconds from boost::chrono::hight_resolution_clock::time_point?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++-chrono

I am new to boost and chrono. I am writing a logger that logs the timestamps of API calls, entry and exit. I tried using boost::xtime first, but it wasn't giving the high resolution value I needed. Hence was thinking about using Chrono. I declared a boost::chrono::hight_resolution_clock::time_stamp x; variable for getting the timestamp and assigned it to boost::chrono::hight_resolution_clock::now ();. Now, I need to get the nanoseconds from this variable and put it in my log file (thats the requirement). So I cast it  boost::chrono::duration_cast (x). But it just wouldn't let me do that. It needs 2 parameters apparently,  and I only have one. Is there a way to get around this?. Is it possible to create another time_stamp variable and assign zero to it and use that variable?. I tried assigning zero, but its not working. Kindly help me out.

Thanks, 
Sam

Comment: Is your target system capable of _nanosecond_ timer resolution actually?

Comment: What time do you want the nanoseconds _since_?  Do you want nanoseconds since the last whole second (a high-resolution timestamp), or do you want nanoseconds since the epoch, or what?

Comment: Yes, my target system is capable of nanoseconds resolution. I need the current time in nanoseconds(high resolution timestamp).

Answer (score 2):

If tagged `c++11`, any reason why not to use `std::chrono`?

```
// Using std::chrono
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  // start timer

/* do some work */

auto diff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start; // get difference 
auto nsec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(diff);
std::cout << "it took: " << nsec.count() << " nanoseconds" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Hi Remis, isn't this solution for getting the delta time in nanoseconds? Is it possible to get the current time in nanoseconds? Please advice

Comment: What do you mean by "current time in nanoseconds"? A timepoint is defined as a duration after an epoch, which is defined by a clock. For example 1970-01-01 is the  epoch of the UNIX systems. So, "current time" is something like 1,470,252,780,000,000,000 nanoseconds since an epoch.

Comment: Look for more info on this in Chapter [5.7. Clocks and Timers](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1881386&seqNum=2) from C++ Standard Library, The: A Tutorial and Reference.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::chrono::duration_cast` converts a duration into the specified units, but you've given it a `boost::chrono::time_point`, not a duration.

There's really no such thing as "*the current time in nanoseconds*".  To get a duration, you need to specify the time since which you want to know how many nanoseconds have elapsed (an "epoch").  Different clocks will measure their time based on different epochs.

`boost::chrono::system_clock` (currently) uses the Unix epoch (midnight Jan 1, 1970) as its epoch, but it's not steady and it may not have the resolution you need (it's in nanoseconds on my Ubuntu box, but in 1/10,000,000ths of a second on my Windows box).

`boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock` uses boot up as its epoch, is steady, and measures time in nanoseconds on both boxes I tested on.

Boost also provides other clocks like `process_cpu_clock` that use other epochs and count in other units.

Thus you can get nanos since Jan 1, 1970 using `system_clock`, but it may not actually be nanosecond-accurate, and it may go backwards if the user changes the system time or the computer syncs with network time, or you can get nanos since some other point in time using `high_resolution_clock`.